# How to extract JSON data from a website that has login in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, response, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to get this data from the website, in python:
[Data seen from the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdymg.png)

What's the best way to get that json from the website?

What I've tried so far:

1. Saving to HAR.

It saves everything and I only want that json object. I've been trying to keep it as "last resort" since it's a manual operation.

2. Selenium.

I used selenium for a couple of automations so it was my first go to. The web page has login with 2 factor authentication, so I had to use a profile already logged in. Tried to just get the response in python but it was blocked.

Then I tried to get the response with seleniumrequests, which didn't work as well.

Lastly I tried loading cookies from the logged instance of selenium to the request, didn't work.

I'm kinda lost, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these are XHR requests you could grab this information using [Selenium Wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire). It works the same way standard Selenium does, but with the added functionality of capturing requests and handling them.

Comment: Thanks Roman I was able to extract the json this way.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, glad to have helped! :)